# Association test to get p values and OR in plink2, and file input format

Tags: files, input

Are there any commands for association testing in plink2 which will output p-value and OR in the resulting output file? If so, what kind of file input do I need to use for such commands...a vcf.gz file currently for an ecDNA+ cancer group and an ecDNA- cancer group which I'm using in a GWAS.

Comment: You may find [bioinformatics.stackexchange.com](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plink) more appropriate

Comment: Voting to close the question here, since OP asked it at bioinformatics after following the suggestion, which is most certainly a better place to ask about a very specialized command. ( https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17607/association-test-to-get-p-values-and-or-in-plink2-and-file-input-format )